# Mac keyboard on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, hardware

I've been looking for keyboard:

- slim
- quiet (not mechanical)
- tenkeyless
- wireless
- with standard layout (symetric control keys, full size arrow keys, page-up and page-down keys etc.)

And I cannot find anything for PC. But this keyboard is pretty much what I need:
https://matias.store/products/fk408btb

The problem is that I don't know how it works on Linux and cannot find anything interesting on google. What I'm especially interested in are diacritics. Does mac keyboards need some kind of remapping? If not then "option" and "command" keys work as "window key" and "alt" respectively? Does the right "command" key works as the right "alt" key (i.e. does it allow to make diacritics?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicly the command <kbd>⌘</kbd> works as <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>, left option <kbd>⌥</kbd> as <kbd>Alt</kbd> and right as <kbd>AltGr</kbd>. It should be possible to remap/swap <kbd>⌥</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>.

If you're interested in altering your layout for diacritics I'm using my own layout heavily based on [queria/vok](https://github.com/queria/vok) which is CZ/SK typographic layout (qwerty and qwertz) containing even special punctuation characters and more `… „ “ - – —`.
Diacritics is available via <kbd>Alt-LETTER</kbd> and for letters having two different diacritics using <kbd>Alt-Shift-LETTER</kbd>. For example <kbd>Alt-e</kbd> results in `é` and <kbd>Alt-Shfift-e</kbd> is `ě`. Even though if you're not from CZ/SK, it could be a good starting point for inspiration how to create a custom layout. Here are my macOS layout variant screenshots [jindraj/vok](https://github.com/jindraj/vok/blob/vok4mac/README.md) to show you how comfortably the diacritics could be mapped.

Ad keyboard, as a [Matias Laptop Pro](https://matias.store/products/laptop-pro-keyboard-for-mac) owner I can only recommend their boards. I was always tempted to buy their aluminium keyboard for their nice design, battery life and price.